# Thread doesn't change priority C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I'm using threads in my program written in C++ for Linux and need to change one's priority. For this purpose I utilize ***pthread_setschedparam()*** function, so my code looks like:

```
struct sched_param thread_param; 
thread_param.sched_priority = 2; 
pthread_setschedparam(tid[current_thread], SCHED_RR, &thread_param);
```

where ***tid*** is an array of ***pthread_t** and* **current_thread** is the index of this array. Why after executing this code I still see thread without priority changed? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the return value

Comment: Return value is 22

Comment: Check the return value _with code that can print a proper error message_. **Always** check the return value, especially from C API functions that return error codes. When you know what `22` means, read the manpage again and then look at the linked question.